# Firemonkey custom component

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, custom-component, delphi-xe8

I'm trying to create a cross-platform component for FireMonkey on Delphi XE8...

But I'm facing some problems. Although up the properties "Width" and "Height" in the Object Inspector to compile apparently the size settings are ignored. And when I reopen the project my component is also small. (I noticed that the width and height settings are not saved to the DFM file).

Note: All other native components of FireMonkey work properly, just my custom not.

Whats the problem?

```
unit FMX.Card;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Graphics, System.Types;

type

TCardNum = (Ace, Deuce, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King);

TCardSuit = (Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades);

TCard = class(TControl)
private
  { Private declarations }
  FCardBack: TBitmap;
  FCardDown: Boolean;
  FCardSet: TBitmap;
  FCardNum: TCardNum;
  FCardSuit: TCardSuit;
  procedure SetCardDown(AValue: Boolean);
  procedure SetCardNum(AValue: TCardNum);
  procedure SetCardSuit(AValue: TCardSuit);
protected
  { Protected declarations }
  procedure Paint; override;
public
  { Public declarations }
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
destructor Destroy; override;
published
  { Published declarations }
  property Position;
  property RotationAngle;
  property Width;
  property Height;
  property CardDown: Boolean read FCardDown write FCardDown;
  property CardNum: TCardNum read FCardNum write FCardNum;
  property CardSuit: TCardSuit read FCardSuit write FCardSuit;
end;

implementation

{$R 'CardResource.res'}

const
  DEFAULT_CARD_WIDTH  = 71;
  DEFAULT_CARD_HEIGHT = 96;

{ TCard }

constructor TCard.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var
  LRStream: TResourceStream;
begin
  inherited;
  LRStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'CardBack', RT_RCDATA);
  try
    FCardBack := TBitmap.CreateFromStream(LRStream);
  finally
    LRStream.Free;
  end;
  LRStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'CardSet', RT_RCDATA);
  try
    FCardSet := TBitmap.CreateFromStream(LRStream);
  finally
    LRStream.Free;
  end;
end;

destructor TCard.Destroy;
begin
  FCardBack.Free;
  FCardSet.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TCard.Paint;
var
  LLeft: Single;
  LTop: Single;
begin
  inherited;
  Canvas.BeginScene;
  try
    if FCardDown then
      Canvas.DrawBitmap(FCardBack, TRectF.Create(0, 0, FCardBack.Width, FCardBack.Height), TRectF.Create(0, 0, Width, Height), 1.0)
    else
    begin
      LLeft := Ord(FCardNum) * DEFAULT_CARD_WIDTH;
      LTop := Ord(FCardSuit) * DEFAULT_CARD_HEIGHT;
      Canvas.DrawBitmap(FCardSet, TRectF.Create(LLeft, LTop, LLeft + DEFAULT_CARD_WIDTH, LTop + DEFAULT_CARD_HEIGHT), TRectF.Create(0, 0, Width, Height), 1.0);
    end;
  finally
    Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to include your code

Comment: David my code is really big so I posted: http://pastebin.com/s49hiBs4

Comment: Please cut the code down to a minimal amount that demonstrates the problem and post that. Yes that will take you time, but you'll get better help that way.

Comment: Does it related to your issue https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2013/12/30/removing-a-fmx-controls-size-restrictions/ ?

Comment: David this is the question, I don't know where is the problem. Is not really big, is a simple custom component. But, seems that it's a bug of Firemonkey. It's a TCard descendent by TControl with "property Width;" and "property Height" on "published".

Comment: Questions here asking *Why isn't this code working?* must include the **relevant** portions of the code here, in the question itself. Posting a link off-site is not acceptable; if that off-site location is unavailable (off-line, moved, etc.) the code is not available for future readers, and therefore the question loses all meaning. If you want help, trim the code down to a MCVE and post it here.

Comment: Ok Ken, I'll edit the post. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's the first time that I ask here, I apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is add the "property Size;" on published too.

```
published
  { Published declarations }
  property Size;
  property Width;
  property Height;
```

If you just add "Height" and "Width" will only work at design-time.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help me.